# Video tag autoplay pauses when user navigates away from page

Tags: python, reactjs, typescript, video

I got a video tag that looks like this

```
<video
        muted
        controls
        autoPlay
        src={videoSrc}
        width="640px"
        height="480px"
        onEnded={handleOnEnded}
        ref={videoRef}
      />
```

streaming in video from a websocket via the react state videoSrc (createObjectUrl on blobs streamed by websockets). This works fine.

However, the problem is that before the blob finishes playing, if I change tabs, the page is still open (and still playing), the video pauses, and only resumes when I navigate back to the page. Why is this happening? Is it some browser optimisation?

How do I prevent this from happening (I want the video to keep playing, like how when I navigate away from Youtube the video I opened continues playing)

Comment: When I "navigate away" from a page, I expect everything to unload. What am I missing?

Comment: @spender ah, let me clarify that, I dont mean the navigating away, but rather changing tabs (with the same page still open)

Comment: What browsers have you tested this on?
Has the page any blur listeners?
What's the video renderer's default onblur event?
Have you tried adding an onblur override to the video tag?

Comment: @BeavatronPrime I am using chrome 118, and I have not tried using onBlur yet. Can u give me an example how it will help here? 

edit: I have tried adding an onBlur function
```
const handleOnBlur = () => {
    const video = videoRef.current;
    return video?.play();
  };
```
But it did not seem to work. Same issue occurs